# How to add a ViewModel for new pages of Xamarin Native iOS & Android apps

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

**Context**: I am handed this massive enterprise iOS & Android Xamarin Native applications that doesn't use ViewModels or any MVVM framework. It does have a separated Network services layer and it has a lot of pages, so starting over won't make any sense.

**Why the change is needed**: No MVVM, the services layer is called directly from the UI classes (Fragments & ViewControllers), and there is no good abstraction. So I will start with 1 view and then create TechDebt to transform the rest of the app.

**What I know**:

1. Adding MVVM frameworks require creating extensive changes, especially to use Navigation services for Navigating the views, and are best done if added when green-fielding the application.
2. As seen [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android-support/ViewModel/ViewModel/ViewModel/ItemViewModel.cs), Android has an easy way of using a ViewModel but I won't be able to use that for iOS then.
3. I also know that I can launch a Xamarin Forms page instead and that will be all ready for MVVM, since I can just assign the BindingContext property to an instance of the ViewModel.

**What I need**: I need to create one new page for iOS & one for Android. I want to be able to create a ViewModel that's shared between iOS & Android. I want to be able to use it for a single view that I am creating and it should be initialized when the page is loaded.

How can I add 1 viewmodel that's shared by a ViewController & a Fragment? Am I missing something, is it much easier than I am making it?

Comment: Take Customizing a ListView as an example. The model of listview can be used by both iOS and Android. This requires the Forms model to be used in the native renderer to be used in them.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up being able to use MvvmLight for this. Added the Nuget package to the projects, Created a ViewModelBase in the Core Shared Library Project:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase
{
        private PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEventHandler;

        protected bool IsLoading { get; set; }

        public bool RegisteredPropertyEventHandler { get; set; }

        public const string ErrorMessagePropertyName = "ErrorMessage";

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }

        public void RegisterPropertyEventHandler(PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEventHandler)
        {
            this.propertyChangedEventHandler = propertyChangedEventHandler;
            this.PropertyChanged += propertyChangedEventHandler;
            this.RegisteredPropertyEventHandler = true;
        }

        public void UnegisterPropertyEventHandler()
        {
            if (this.RegisteredPropertyEventHandler)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged -= propertyChangedEventHandler;
                this.RegisteredPropertyEventHandler = false;
                this.propertyChangedEventHandler = null;
            }
        }

        public void TearDown()
        {
            this.UnegisterPropertyEventHandler();
        }

        protected void NotifyError (string message)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = message;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => ErrorMessage);
        }
}
```

and a ViewModelLocator

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
        public const string ABCPageKey = "ABCPage";

        public ABCViewModel ABC 
        {
            get 
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ABCViewModel> ();
            }
        }

        public ViewModelLocator ()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider (() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            // Register all of the view models
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ABCViewModel> ();
        }

        public static void Cleanup ()
        {
        }

        public T GetViewModel<T> ()
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T> ();
        }
}
```

On the iOS side, I already had a BaseUIViewController, so I created a BaseViewModelUIViewController on top of it

```
public abstract partial class BaseViewModelUIViewController<T> : BaseUIViewController where T : ViewModelBase
    {
        public T ViewModel 
        {
            get 
            {
                return App.Locator.GetViewModel<T> ();
            }
        }

        public BaseViewModelUIViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        internal virtual void ViewModelPropertyChangedHandler (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (string.Format ("****** Property Changed for {0} in {1}", e.PropertyName, this.GetType ().Name));
            switch (e.PropertyName) 
            {
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

And then Android, similarly I already had a BaseFragment, so I created a BaseViewModelFragment on top of it

```
public class BaseViewModelFragment<T> : BaseFragment where T : ViewModelBase
{
        public T ViewModel 
        {
            get 
            {
                return App.Locator.GetViewModel<T> ();
            }
        }

        public BaseViewModelFragment (string title) : base (title)
        {
        }

        internal virtual void ViewModelPropertyChangedHandler (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (string.Format ("****** Property Changed for {0} in {1}", e.PropertyName, this.GetType ().Name));
            switch (e.PropertyName) 
            {
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        public override void OnDestroyView ()
        {
            this.ViewModel.TearDown ();

            base.OnDestroyView ();
        }
}
```

I hope it makes sense to other people looking for solutions.

Creating ViewModels: So naturally, for every new ViewModel created, I had to register it in the ViewModelLocator.

Using ViewModels: In terms of usage, you can simply use the ViewModel in the UI by inheriting from the ": BaseViewModelUIViewController" for iOS or from ": BaseViewModelFragment" for Android

Comment: Pretty good so far. The app doesn’t have a lot of updates @markwardell so I just added it to the README for a future dev to make any changes. If looking for simplicity, I would probably just do a simple BaseViewModel class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and just do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you don't miss anything, all your claims are proper and you have properly listed various directions that you can take (and that you don't like).

Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS are not made with data binding in mind, but rather with using the native interfaces, only Xamarin.Forms is made for the data binding. The capabilities of native platforms to use the data binding is limited (if it existed it would be incompatible among the platforms and you would have to make separate view models, and there is not data binding for iOS as of now anyway).

So basically there is no data binding in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. It is completely up to you to abstract the shared business model and connect it with the user interface.